# Animated movie that had black robots that turned people into stone late 1960s to 1970s

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

It was a weird sci-fi animated movie I saw only a little bit of it. This is what I recall:

- It was old but had color, so I assume it was late 1960s to early 1970s.
- The animation and style reminded me of [*Fantastic Planet*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070544/) but it wasn't as psychedelic.
- The setting was an alien planet with all sorts of bizarre creatures.
- The tech was advanced but not a dominant aspect of the planet's culture. The people lived simple and peaceful.
- The protagonist is a man with bluish skin like the others.
- The antagonists were humanoid shaped black robots that shot a beam that would turn people into stone.

Comment: Cartoons had color at least as early as live-action movies.   Color *TV* didn't become common until the late 1960s.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would seem like the movie your looking for is called [*Gandahar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film)), though it's not from the time period you stated (it's 1988) it seems to fit all the other criterion.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095525/?ref_=ttmd_md_nm):

> Gandahar is a utopian world of rare beauty and tranquility, the result of extensive mutation and genetic experimentation. But the perfect peace is shattered when a mysterious evil force invades this idyllic serenity, turning people into stone with petrifying rays.

Specifically it has black robots who turn blue people to stone with a ray beam. The people also had advanced technology (the genetic experimentation stuff) but lived "peacefully".
Finally, and interestingly enough *Fantastic Planet* is linked to on IMDb for their similarities in animation style.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it, I remembered the title as an English one, never realized it to be French origin. Thank you, sir.