# Cartoon with blue mutant aliens, one has no head but a face on his torso

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I remember an 80's cartoon movie that had a scene with blue aliens/mutants, one of which had no head but a face on his torso, walking through a forest, did not speak in present tense (everything was/will be fine) I think because the present was too painful for them to contemplate?  This may have been a small scene, rather than the focus of the movie.

Answer (score 4):

You're thinking of the French film [Gandahar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film)).

From [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095525/?from=cross-link-fun):

> This animated film is set on the planet Gandahar, where peace reigns and poverty is unknown. The utopian lifestyle is upset by reports of people at the outlying frontiers being turned to stone. Sent to investigate, Prince Sylvain (John Shea) crashes and is rescued by the Deformed, hideous genetic experiments gone wrong and left to fend for themselves. With their help, Sylvain discovers that the Metamorphosis, a gigantic brain also created in an experiment, is trying to destroy Gandahar.This animated film is set on the planet Gandahar, where peace reigns and poverty is unknown. The utopian lifestyle is upset by reports of people at the outlying frontiers being turned to stone. Sent to investigate, Prince Sylvain (John Shea) crashes and is rescued by the Deformed, hideous genetic experiments gone wrong and left to fend for themselves. With their help, Sylvain discovers that the Metamorphosis, a gigantic brain also created in an experiment, is trying to destroy Gandahar.

The fella you're thinking of is one of the above-mentioned Deformed.

[image: These guys scared me to death as a kid.]

Comment: If so, dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100394/an-animated-movie-that-had-black-robots-that-turned-people-into-stone-late-1960s

Comment: That poor guy on the right, he must hate going to the toilet.